# Why viewDidLoad function is not called?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change `UIBarButton`'s color in the `navigationBar`. To achieve this, in `viewDidLoad:` I put this line:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

Everything works fine until I started to notice something strange. That `UIBarButton` is used to dismiss the `UIViewController`. When it is pressed, I just dismiss the `viewController`. But, if I present it (`viewController`) again, the color of the `UIBarButton` is not white, it gets `tintColor` of the application.

After doing some debugging, I noticed that `viewDidLoad:` is not called again after the `viewController` is just dismissed and presented again. The reason why my `UIBarButton` has a different color is because I change its color in `viewDidLoad:`. When `viewDidLoad:` is not called, of course, color is not changed.

It was an interesting discovery for me the fact that iOS doesn't call `viewDidLoad:` for `UIViewController` that was presented already. Possibly, it is due to the optimisation, because it is not efficient to draw the whole UI every time.

My solution to this problem can be to change color, not in `viewDidLoad:`, but in `viewDidAppear:`. But, is it right approach to solve a problem? And why `viewDidLoad:` is not called in the above situation?

Comment: `viewDidLoad:` calls once for an instance of any controller. So probably you have globally declared that controller and not each time when you present. So basically you did not discover anything interesting you just misunderstood the behaviour.

Comment: For your second query ***in `viewDidAppear:` is it right approach*** - This will not make any effect by performance of the app because you are just setting the colour. But It will take sometime to reflect the colour because `viewDidAppear:` calls after appearing the view.

Comment: Also please keep your question title something related to your problem. This is totes different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you create and store you view controller, but present it wrapped in `UINavigationController`:

```swift
let controller = YourModalViewController()
...
func presentMyModal() {
  present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller))
}
```

In this case your `viewDidLoad` method will be called just once and you'll have visual bug. If you want to leave styling code of your modal inside it's file you can create instance func which will return this controller wrapped and styled.

```swift
extension YourModalViewController {
  func wrappedInNC() -> UINavigationController {
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    // Styling code.
    return nc
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right that I store view controller and present it wrapped inside UINavigationController. You mean that viewDidLoad called only once if it is wrapped inside NC? If it is not, will it be called?

Comment: @neo viewDidLoad called only once per controller instance. It's by design.

Comment: According to iOS guidelines a view controller calls its view didload only once when its loading. later on only view will appear gets called if you not reloading the view controller completely. So whatever code provided above will resolve this problem